# Index Match formula works, but not within COUNTIFS or IF statement

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I've spent over 24 hours pulling my hair out on this one and have searched for the solution here extensively. I've been improving my `INDEX/MATCH` skills over the past few months but have run into a challenge this time. I'm sure someone here can spot the issue.

I'm running `INDEX/MATCH` within an IF statement. Everything works fine with a 1 criteria match and I get the proper result just by using enter (don't seem to need to use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd>).

```
IF(INDEX(transactions!$A:$E,MATCH(UI$1,transactions!$D:$D,0),5)=$A16,"DNP","with " & INDEX(transactions!$A:$E,MATCH(UI$1,transactions!$D:$D,0),5)))
```

and I get the proper result. However if I add 1 more criteria to the `INDEX/MATCH`in the if statement and press <kbd>Enter</kbd> alone I get a `#N/A` error. If I use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> I get the wrong result (the false value of the `IF` statement).

The `INDEX/MATCH formula` with the 2 criteria gives the PROPER OUTPUT when used on its own

```
INDEX(transactions!$A:$E,MATCH(1,(transactions!$D:$D=UI$1)*(transactions!$A:$A<=C16),0),5)
```

But, again, when added in to the same `IF` statement above in place of the single criteria match, I get the errors mentioned above. Any thoughts?

**UPDATE:** Here it is placed in its `IF` statement and it now runs fine. I had an extra bracket that was causing a problem

```
IF(INDEX(transactions!$A:$E,MATCH(1,(transactions!$D:$D=UI$1)*(transactions!$A:$A<=C16),0),5)=$A16,"DNP","with " & INDEX(transactions!$A:$E,MATCH(UI$1,transactions!$D:$D,0),5))
```

BUT now the issue is when I insert into a nested `IF` statement I was using it in. I now get the false outcome every time ("LEAVE BLANK"), which is not the desired outcome.

```
IF(COUNTIFS(transactions!$D:$D,INDIRECT(ADDRESS(1,COLUMN(),1)),transactions!$A:$A,"<="&INDIRECT("C"&ROW()))>0, IF(INDEX(transactions!$A:$E,MATCH(1,(transactions!$D:$D=UI$1)*(transactions!$A:$A<=C16),0),5)=$A16,"DNP","with " & INDEX(transactions!$A:$E,MATCH(UI$1,transactions!$D:$D,0),5)), IF(COUNTIFS(stats!$B:$B,INDIRECT(ADDRESS(1,COLUMN(),1)),stats!$A:$A,INDIRECT("A"&ROW()))=1,"DNP","LEAVE BLANK"))
```

Comment: Please show the IF formula with the multiple criteria Index/Match.  A single IndexMatch is not an array formula and thus does not need the CSE, but the multiple does require the CSE.

Comment: Hi @ScottCraner. I updated the original post with the additional information.

Comment: indirect raises a warning flag...is the address that indirect is dealing with in the same workbook or a workbook that is already opened?  if the answer is yes, then nothing to worry about.  if the answer is no, that may be the issue

Comment: @ForwardEd Yes. In the same sheet actually. I couldn't find a better way of referencing the 1st row in the column since I'm running this formula through a macro (eventually)

Comment: `ROW(A$1)` will always be row 1 dues the $ and the A will update as the cell is copied left and right

Comment: Did you break down each component of your formula to see if they behave as expected independently?

Comment: I did. And all components (3 different IF statements) used separately gave the right response. But together, the assembled formula always gave the default false result. However, I went back and looked at the indirects again. I changed them all to direct cell references, and it WORKS. Thanks @ForwardEd

Comment: Now I have to open a new question about a macro to fill blank cells with an array formula. I have one that can enter a formula into blanks cells, but not an array formula.

Answer (score 0):

All components (3 different IF statements) used separately gave the right response separately. But together, the assembled formula always gave the default false result. However, I went back and looked at the indirects again. I changed them all to direct cell references, and it WORKS